# Ceramic Capacitor Specs

Tags: capacitor

I am repairing a Haier RF-5210-11 refrigerator power control board; found this damaged capacitor. The circuit board has a "RTC" designation on it at the capacitor location, and the capacitor itself is only labeled with 005  04. I cannot find any information on the specs for this capacitor so I can replace it. Any one have information on this capacitor?[image]

Comment: Are you sure its a capacitor and not a PTC, or NTC? Also, capacitors don't usually just explode on their own. Something else causes them to.

Comment: I agree with user @DKNguyen possibly it is a PTC and not RTC. Anyway, if you replace it it will probably blow again.

Comment: Maybe an NTC thermistor for surge elimination. If it was in series with the power, then probably that's it. But if it gave up the ghost probably some semiconductors have run down the curtain and joined the choir invisible.

Comment: These devices are like resettable fuses, so if they blow then something downstream shorted out, or a motor has a stuck rotor, etc. These devices only protect against high inrush currents, not short circuits.

Comment: According to googling pictures of the said power supply, there is a green part designated RTC right at the mains input. It must be the inrush limiting NTC thermistor, not a capacitor.

Comment: Thanks greatly for the clarification; yes, most likely a NTC thermistor. The unit keeps blowing fuses, and so far I have found three bad diodes. I will check all the capacitors and replace the four transitors just for insurance. This circuit card is no longer available so trying to repair it is my only option.

Comment: [Photo of damaged component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5T91G.jpg) This is a picture of mine on my RF-5210-11. Did anyone ever find a replacement part for this RTC? Everytime I plug the Haier Wine Cooler in, the buss fuse blows. Obviously, the step down of AC current is overloading the fuse.

Comment: I eventually tracked down Part# 954-5D2-10LC from Mouser Electronics
It's a Semitec NTC Thermistor 5ohms 4amps
I'm still troubleshooting the circuit card, but at least it powers up now

Answer (score 1):

This part limits the [inrush current](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inrush_current) to the input capacitors of a switching power supply. These capacitors draw large current when power is applied and will get warm due to power dissipation. When they fail they will leak and swell, forming a low resistance. The same value is commonly used in laptop power supplies.

Be sure to check for a bad MOV surge suppressor. These normally fail shorted but with replacing the fuse several times they have been known to read as a open.